# Issue with RStudio Server in Singularity Container: User Privilege and UID Switching

Tags: r, docker, hpc, rstudio-server, singularity-container

Description:
I have been successfully converting a Docker container to a Singularity container using the steps provided on https://rocker-project.org/use/singularity.html.

```bash
singularity pull docker://rocker/rstudio
```

However, when attempting to start RStudio Server within the Singularity container, I encountered an unexpected issue.

The command used for the Singularity container version 4.3.1 is as follows:

```bash
singularity exec --bind run:/run,var-lib-rstudio-server:/var/lib/rstudio-server,database.conf:/etc/rstudio/database.conf \
rstudio_4.3.1.sif \
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver --www-address=127.0.0.1
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in the following error message:

"**ERROR Attempt to run server as user 'rstudio-server' (uid 999) from account 'rstudio' (uid 1000) without privilege, which is required to run as a different uid; LOGGED FROM: virtual rstudio::core::ProgramStatus rstudio::server::Options::read(int, char* const*, std::ostream&) src/cpp/server/ServerOptions.cpp:318**"

Surprisingly, when I tried using a pre-built Singularity container for version 4.1.0 from https://github.com/j-andrews7/singularity-rstudio with the same command:

```bash
singularity exec --bind run:/run,var-lib-rstudio-server:/var/lib/rstudio-server,database.conf:/etc/rstudio/database.conf \
rstudio_4.1.0.sif \
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver --www-address=127.0.0.1
```

It was successful, and RStudio Server started without any issues.

Upon investigating the user lists within the two containers, I noticed a slight difference. The successfully started 4.1 container does not have an 'rstudio' user, while the 4.3.1 container contains an 'rstudio' user with the same UID (1000) as my host OS user.

```bash
cat /etc/passwd

...
rstudio-server:x:999:999::/home/rstudio-server:/bin/sh
rstudio:x:1000:1000::/home/rstudio:/bin/bash
kchen:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/kchen:/bin/bash
```

```bash
cat /etc/passwd
...

rstudio-server:x:999:999::/home/rstudio-server:/bin/sh
kchen:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/kchen:/bin/bash
```

Environment:

Singularity version: 3.5.2
Docker version (if applicable): 24.0.5
RStudio Server version: latest 4.3.1
Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04

How can I sovle this question and use Rstudio server in singularity container.